# How do I get the Source of an Image on GestureCompleted

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7

I want to find the URI of an Image on the phone screen when the image is dragged.
I have many images on the screen and I need to know which one has been dragged, I can easily find that from the filename of the image as they are named `A.png, B.png and so on`.

```
    private void OnGestureCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e){
        Image image = sender as Image;
        TranslateTransform transform = image.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
        //storing the final values after the gesture is complete
        xFin = (e.GetPosition(null).X);
        yFin = (e.GetPosition(null).Y);
        //failed attempts to convert adress to string
        MessageBox.Show(image.Source.ToString());
    }
```

This returns `System.Windows.Controls.Image`.
and this on the other hand throws an exception stating that ConvertToString hasn't been implemented.

```
ImageSourceConverter convertor = new ImageSourceConverter();
string location = convertor.ConvertToString(image);
MessageBox.Show(location);
```

Is there some way this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the `Source` property is `BitmapImage` (which it probably is if you are passing in a URI to the `Image` in the `Source` property in XAML) then you can use UriSource:

```
MessageBox.Show(((BitmapImage)image.Source).UriSource.ToString());
```

I suggest you use the `Tag` property of the `Image` control to store the info you need though. More scalable robust in the long run.

Comment: Thanks so much, the tag property was exactly what I was looking for but wasn't aware of it.